# Opposite category of Cat

Tags: category-theory

Is there an explicit way of describing the opposite category of $\mathbf{Cat}$, or at least the opposite of the category of small categories? By explicit I mean something like the equivalence between $\mathbf{Set}^{op}$ and the category of complete atomic boolean algebras.

Comment: Such equivalences are very rare: no example seriously different from Gelfand dualtiy comes to mind. Part of the reason for this is that the opposite of a locally presentable category (i.e. almost any natural cocomplete category except spaces) can never be locally presentable. Both complete atomic boolean algebras and compact Hausdorff spaces, the two examples brought up so far, get around this by being locally presentable in a larger universe-they're algebraic, you just have to allow operations with arbitrarily many arguments. But there seem to be few such categories.

Comment: To expand on this a bit, the opposite of $\mathbf{Cat}$ is much worse than locally presentable. It doesn't even admit a generating set of objects, since $\mathbf{Cat}$ admits no cogenerating set-the special adjoint functor theorem fails for $\mathbf{Cat}$ for the same reason as it fails for groups (the limit-preserving functor of maps from a product of simple groups of a large number of cardinalities is values in small sets but not representable.) So the opposite of $\mathbf{Cat}$ can't even be, in any sense, algebraic. This is a level of weirdness matched only by the homotopy category.

Comment: @mfox I suggest you to slightly rephrase the question, as I find the motivation you gave me privately quite enlightening about the kind of answer you might find spot-on. :)

Comment: If morphisms in $\text{Cat}$ are $\text{Set}$s and $\text{CompBoolAlg} \sim \text{Set}^\text{op}$ why not just rephrase $\text{Cat}$ as a cocategory in $\text{CompBoolAlg}$?